# How do I insert a field to display above the Content field in WordPress Posts?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need WordPress Posts to pull a database entity they are not normally supposed to and display the field above the Content output.

Details:

- Videos are being uploaded to Vimeo via plugin, which is throwing the iframe code into the database in a convenient and ordered way.
- Posts need to display these videos followed by some simple text content.
- The Post needs to pull this particular db entry (the iframe) and display it directly above the Content area.

If you could point me to a plugin which manages this, awesome. Otherwise, I'm not sure how to handle this except to change the default method WordPress displays its Posts. While that's not terrible, it's not ideal, as I presume each update would wipe the changes.

Answer (score 1):

This was my question, and I solved it years ago. I am answering it for closure.

1. Modified PHP files can be preserved by cloning them into the [Child Theme](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-wordpress-child-theme-video/).
2. Copy over WP's single.php to the correct location in your Child Theme (there is [copious documentation](https://themezee.com/docs/how-to-override-template-files/) and a bit of nuance to this process). WP's PHP files are matryoshka dolls, so you may end up copying over a dozen files for one page type.
3. Read through the files and clone or modify what you need to deliver your final result.
4. How to pull from the database: [Link1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233086/how-to-fetch-data-in-wordpress-using-mysqli-or-wpdb) and [Link2](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-display-specific-data-from-custom-database-table-in-wordpress/) will help
5. Profit